# Jquery :first selector and fadeIn(), child divs not coming along for the ride

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page I am working on and am trying to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` specific `div`s. However, when I fade in a `div` using the `:first` selector, I only get the parent `div` and none of it's children.

Javascript (Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                setupLeftMenu(); //creates nav menu
                autoHeight(); //auto scales content
                $('.datatable').dataTable(); //creates sortable table, injects divs that are not showing up when 'fadeIn' is used.
                $('#outer div').hide();
                $('.submenu li:first').attr('id','current');
                $('#outer div:first').fadeIn('slow');
                $('.submenu li a').click(function() {
                    var top = $(this);
                    $('#outer div').fadeOut('slow');
                    $('.submenu li').attr('id','');
                    $(this).parent().attr('id','current');
                    $('#' + $(top).attr('name')).fadeIn('slow');

                    }); 
                });
```

And this is the HTML code I get in return. Notice the `display:none` on the child `div`s.

```
 <div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="example_wrapper" style="display: block;">
   <div id="example_length" class="dataTables_length" style="display: none;"> 
     <label>Show 
       <select size="1" name="example_length">
         <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
         <option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option>
         <option value="100">100</option>
       </select>
        entries
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="dataTables_filter" id="example_filter" style="display: none;">
     <label>Search: 
       <input type="text">
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Does this have to do with the child `div`s being created by the other Javascript code? I looked into the `:first-child` selector, but that seems to only affect the first child of multiple parents, rather than all the children of the first parent. I also assumed that the children would automatically follow suit. What am I doing wrong here and how should I fix my code so that all of the children of `div id="example_wrapper"` `fadeIn` with it? Thanks!

***Update***

Just wanted to include my revised code now that I got it working. Still some tweaks to be made but the issue of the child `div`s is fully resolved. As @Ben Felda said, the elements didn't exist yet. What I did was add a `callback` function to the `dataTable` function which forced the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effects and the attribute changes to wait until the `div`s were fully formed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                setupLeftMenu();
                autoHeight();
                $('#outer div').hide();
                $('.submenu li:first').attr('id','current');
                $('#outer div:first').fadeIn('slow');
                var dbCallBack = $('.submenu a').click(function() {
                                    var top = $(this);
                                    $('#outer div').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                        $('.submenu li').attr('id','');
                                        $(top).attr('id','current');
                                        $('#' + $(top).attr('name')).fadeIn('slow');
                                    });                         
                                }); 
                $('.datatable').dataTable(dbCallBack);                  
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say without seeing the other functions, but you may be onto the problem that the elements don't exist yet.  Try logging the length property of the element to see if its there.

```
console.log($('.submenu li:first').length)
```

Based on your comment, it seems that the element doesn't exist yet.  Here is what I would do:  Refactor the code based on the [callback pattern](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/).  In a nutshell, you will need to pull out your click event into a separate function, and pass that function name with the call to build the elements.  Very useful pattern!

Comment: Alright, so when log the length property outside of the `click()` it returns "1" however, if I place the log inside of the `click()` I get nothing returned. This is using Chrome's stock console as well as Firefox w/ Firebug 1.11.1. I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to Javascript, what does this mean? Thanks! Also, +1 for getting the ball rolling!

Comment: When you place it inside the click handler, there is time allowed to build the element before you actually perform the click.  Outside the click function, you are logging it as the script is executing. I will update my answer with a suggestion for this